# Can one PowerShell SSH without storing key on disk?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, azure-keyvault, ssh-keys

How can one create a PowerShell session from a Windows10 VM to an RHEL8 VM in Azure **without storing the SSH key on disk?** Looks like the [`New-PSSession` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession?view=powershell-7.1#example-13--create-a-session-using-ssh-and-specify-the-port-and-user-authentication-key) doesn't accept SSH key as string.

```
$pssession = New-PSSession -Name RHELSession -HostName <> -Port 22 -Subsystem powershell -UserName <> -KeyFilePath .\<>.pem -SSHTransport
Invoke-Command -Session $pssession -ScriptBlock {hostname}
```

Can one [Get-AzSshKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azsshkey?view=azps-6.4.0#example-1) or [Get-AzKeyVaultSecret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvaultsecret?view=azps-6.4.0#example-5--get-the-plain-text-value-of-the-current-version-of-a-specific-secret) and provide the key from memory without storing the .pem file on disk?

```
(Get-AzSshKey -ResourceGroupName <> -Name <>).publicKey
```

Comment: SSH.NET assembly supports loading key from memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, `New-PSSession` currently (pwsh v7.1) only allows loading an SSH key from a file. There have been [some](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8035) [requests](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5782) to add that functionality, but starting SSH sessions using the `PSSession` cmdlets is still very limited.

For now, using the basic `ssh.exe` is more straightforward and should be able to do what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Could there be any other cmdlet in the gallery that could accept the key as a string or is it a PowerShell limitation?

Comment: @AyanMullick `Posh-SSH` might allow a string value, but I haven't tested it myself. Most are just wrappers for the windows OpenSSH client, which does not seem to support loading keys from the command line.

Comment: It accepts the key as a string. But then also prompts for a password.

`New-SSHSession -ComputerName <> -Port 22 -Credential <> -KeyString $(Get-AzSshKey -ResourceGroupName <> -Name <>).publicKey -AcceptKey`

Couldn't get it to work.